# How to stop media buffering in NPAPI plugin

Tags: flash, npapi

I wanted to stop the buffering of media data in my NPAPI plugin. My plugin is wrapper written on top of the Adobe flash NPAPI plugin. Which call I shall call to Adobe NPAPI plugin so that it willl stop the buffering of the media content.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Barring knowledge of internal implementation details of Adobe flash or some flash API you could usually call from javascript to do this, you can't.  This is not something that NPAPI controls.

If you're loading flash yourself with your own special npapi interface then it *might* be possible to interfere with the system api calls it's making, or possibly they could be using NPN_GetUrl and related methods for their content loading, but regardless this will be fragile and likely to break in the future.